# Using notifications with bluepy&Sensirion Smartgadget

Tags: python, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to use notifications for temperature updates on a Sensirion Smartgadget. So far everything works: connecting, reading data by polling.

I don't know how to enable the notifications on the Sensirion Smartgadget. What do I have to send to which characteristic?

The only documentation I found was [this](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/2_Humidity_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT3x_Smart-Gadget_User-Guide.pdf) on page 10.

Since now I tried the following which did not work:

```
from bluepy import btle
from bluepy.btle import Peripheral

class MyDelegate(btle.DefaultDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        btle.DefaultDelegate.__init__(self)

    def handleNotification(self, cHandle, data):
        print('notification arrived')


p = Peripheral(myAddress, "random")
p.setDelegate( MyDelegate() )

svc = p.getServiceByUUID( "00002234-b38d-4985-720e-0f993a68ee41" )
ch = svc.getCharacteristics( "00002235-b38d-4985-720e-0f993a68ee41" )[0]

ch.write((1).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little'))
ch.write((1).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
ch.write((1).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))
ch.write((2).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big'))
ch.write((2).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little'))
ch.write((2).to_bytes(2, byteorder='big'))
ch.write((2).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))

while True:
    if p.waitForNotifications(1.0):
        continue

    print("Waiting...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted investigating in the problem and found a brute force solution I didn't see back then...

Iterated over all the results of `getCharacteristics` and wrote `0x01` to them. Turned out I needed to write to the third characteristic the value to turn on notifications.

I started an API on GitHub for the Sensirion, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Mailblocker/pySmartGadget).